# Qt - How to show image/icon/data while dragging an item?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an application where I can drag an item to a QGraphicsScene and create a new object depending on the item text, but how can I change the data being displayed while moving around the item?

for example, instead of a text, I want to show an icon:

[image]

I have a list with some itens:

```
OptionList::OptionList(QWidget *parent) : QListWidget(parent)
{
    this->setDragEnabled(true);
    this->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    this->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);
    this->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);

    for(const QString &color : {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"})
    {
        OptionItem *item = new OptionItem;
        item->setText(color);
        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled| Qt::ItemIsSelectable| Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
        addItem(item);
    }
}
```

I drop the itens into the scene to create a new object:

```
MyScene::MyScene()
{
    setBackgroundBrush(Qt::lightGray);
}

void MyScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    if(event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"))
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void MyScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    if(event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"))
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void MyScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    QByteArray encoded = event->mimeData()->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QStringList colors;

    while (!stream.atEnd())
    {
        int row, col;
        QMap<int,  QVariant> roleDataMap;
        stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;
        colors << roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
    }

    QPointF posView = event->scenePos() ;

    for(const QString & color: colors)
    {
        Block *newBlock = new Block(color);
        newBlock->setPos(posView);
        addItem(newBlock);
    }
}
```

Then, I created OptionItem class, derived from QListWidgetItem, and reimplemented the mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent

```
OptionItem::OptionItem()
{

}

void OptionItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void OptionItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(event->widget());

    QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData;

    QImage image(":/images/MyIcon_icon.png");
    mime->setImageData(image);

    drag->setMimeData(mime);
    drag->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    drag->setHotSpot(QPoint(15, 30));

    drag->exec();

    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void OptionItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    event->setAccepted(true);
}
```

I tried to follow the drag drop robot example in the Qt Creator but it isn't the same thing

It seems that the image appears very quickly when I start dragging an item

Is there a way to show the icon while dragging the item through the whole operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes that inherit from `QAbstractItemView` support the default drag so they already have implemented methods, instead the example you point out shows how to implement this functionality for some class that does not have it, the task in your case is simple, you must overwrite the method `startDrag` of `QListWidget`.

**optionilist.h**

```
#ifndef OPTIONLIST_H
#define OPTIONLIST_H

#include <QListWidget>


class OptionList: public QListWidget{
public:
    OptionList(QWidget* parent=nullptr);

protected:
    void startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions);
};

#endif // OPTIONLIST_H
```

**optionlist.cpp**

```
#include "optionlist.h"

#include <QDrag>

OptionList::OptionList(QWidget *parent): QListWidget(parent){

    setDragEnabled(true);
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);
    setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);

    for(const QString &color : {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"}){
        QListWidgetItem *blue = new QListWidgetItem;
        blue->setText(color);
        blue->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled| Qt::ItemIsSelectable| Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
        addItem(blue);
    }
}

void OptionList::startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions){
    if(supportedActions & Qt::CopyAction){
        QList<QListWidgetItem *> m_items = selectedItems();
        if(m_items.isEmpty())
            return;
        QMimeData *data = mimeData(m_items);
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QPixmap pixmap(":/images/MyIcon_icon.png");
        drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
        drag->setMimeData(data);
        drag->setHotSpot(pixmap.rect().center());
        drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction);
    }
    else
        QListWidget::startDrag(supportedActions);

}
```

<sub>The complete code can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50279503).</sub>

Comment: I used the method startDrag in the QListWidget, and when i start dragging the item, the application output prints the following error: QDrag: No mimedata set before starting the drag

Comment: I used the debugger and it looks like the variable data has no value when it reaches drag->setMimeData(data); maybe the problem is with the mimeData() function?

The application runs succefully but the moment I try to drag an item, the message "QDrag: No mimedata set before starting the drag" appears in the application output.

I also tried to compile your code but i had to set CONFIG += c++11 at the .pro file because of the nullptr identifier, the same message still appears in the application output.

Comment: I tried with your project and got the same message. I already eliminated the OptionItem implementation. I'm using the Qt 5.4.1 Version. Here's the link to my code: https://github.com/Gabriel-22/myqt/tree/master/Project1

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct!

Also should note that `drag->setMimeData(data);` needs to be called after `drag->setPixmap(pixmap);`.

Otherwise, during the drag moving, it will show the original mimedata type instead of showing an image/icon.